# Is it bad to write "the rest of the gang"?

Tags: slang, business-language

One person proposed something, then I told him my personal opinion. The I told him "...but I still need to discuss this issue with the rest of the gang". I mean my colleague and superiors.

Is this bad?

Comment: I mean rest and I did fix it. :)

Comment: In many if not most hierarchically-organized workplaces, some or all of your "superiors" would not like to hear you including them in [your] ***gang***. It might also give the false impression to your *peers* that you personally have a closer relationship with your bosses than is really the case. So I would avoid it.

Comment: It's not bad where I work.  It's used commonly.  I wouldn't give it a second thought.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it in an informal context, so long as there is no danger that the hearer/reader might take "gang" literally to mean a bunch of thugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean 'the *rest* of the gang'? The problem with this phrase is that it is very informal and it shouldn't be heard by your superiors, if you don't want to get into trouble at work :-)

I would simply say 'superiors' if you mean 'superiors', and otherwise 'colleagues' works just fine here.